# Why does scorecard not respond what I want to realize

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

I want to create a scorecard for a game. But I am new to Python. See any help is appreciated.
What I want to realize is a scorecard, that when 5000 points is reached the round stops ans the other players that didn’t have their turns, they still mat finished there turn.

Thanks!

This is the code that I have until now:

```
players = []


def howManyPlayers ():
    countPlayers = int(input("How many players: "))
    for x in range(countPlayers):
        namePlayer = input("Name Player: ")
        players.append(namePlayer)
    print(players)
    print("Let the game begin!")    

def game():
    scorePlayers = {}
    number = 0
    newScore = 0
    while number < 5000:
        for player in players:
            number = int(input("Score: "))
            newScore = newScore + number
            scorePlayers[player] = newScore
            for key, value in scorePlayers.items():
                print(key,value)
    else: print("Game over")


howManyPlayers()
game()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the scorecard to work, add the input score to the specific player. The loop checks for the max score > 5000 then exits.

Try this code:

```
players = []


def howManyPlayers ():
    countPlayers = int(input("How many players: "))
    for x in range(countPlayers):
        namePlayer = input("Name Player: ")
        players.append(namePlayer)
    print(players)
    print("Let the game begin!")    

def game():
    scorePlayers = {k:0 for k in players} # each player starts at 0
    while max(scorePlayers.values()) < 5000:  # exit when any score >= 5000
        for player in players:
            number = int(input(f"Score {player}: "))
            scorePlayers[player] += number  # add to player score
            if scorePlayers[player] >= 5000: print(f'Player {player} wins!')
            for key, value in scorePlayers.items():
                print(key,value)
    else: print("Game over")


howManyPlayers()
game()
```

Output (to confirm all players get a turn)

```
How many players: 3
Name Player: a
Name Player: b
Name Player: c
['a', 'b', 'c']
Let the game begin!
Score a: 5000
a 5000
b 0
c 0
Score b: 2
a 5000
b 2
c 0
Score c: 3
a 5000
b 2
c 3
Game over
```

Comment: There is still only one thing that doesn’t work yet. With this code it breaks the while loop when the total score is 5000, but I want when someone individual reaches the score of 5000. Then it have to break the loop and if someone has one turn left he can still fill in the score, after then game over